# How to work with transactions and stored procedures in Go

Tags: mysql, go

I want to call some stored procedure from Go that has transactions to make the execution atomic.

I read this article here: http://go-database-sql.org/modifying.html

> You should not mingle the use of transaction-related functions such as
>   Begin() and Commit() with SQL statements such as BEGIN and COMMIT in
>   your SQL code. Bad things might result

It says that I should avoid using BEGIN / COMMIT, and I also assume START TRANSACTION in my SQL if I use Begin() and Commit().

What if I made a stored procedure that contained START TRANSACTION and COMMIT.

Could I just skip the Begin() and Commit() functions in Go, and just do an Exec() like this?

```
query := `CALL comment_branch_delete(?, ?);`
if _, err := mysql.DB.Exec(query, commentId, postId); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Would this be atomic? If the comment_branch_delete stored procedure contains `START TRANSACTION` AND `COMMIT`?

Or should I use Tx variable?

Comment: `Can skip the Begin() and Commit() functions in Go if the stored procedure handles the atomic operations ?` yes. `Would this be atomic? If the comment_branch_delete stored procedure contains START TRANSACTION AND COMMIT?` Can t say for sure if we can not read the SP, in principles yes.

Comment: you're executing only one query you don't have to use a Go transaction